# JMX Profiling does not work with maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, jmx

I'm running maven unit test from windows console:

```
mvn -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote ^
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false ^
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false ^
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1100 ^
-Dtest=TimetableEngineTest test
```

However no open port 1100 is shown in `netstat -a` and VisualVM cannot connect to: `127.0.0.1:1100` when choosing "Add JMX Connection" (I have tried it even with my external ip).

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: VisualVM can connect to one of your processes on the same machine without setting any options.  Are you sure the program hasn't finished before you get a chance to connect to it?

Comment: What I do is profile my unit tests in my IDE.  I select the test and click select profile.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutly sure process is running.

Comment: In that case VisualM should be able to connect it without changing settings. Can you see it with `jps -lvm` ?

Comment: Yes, jps can see it. I have more than one JVM on my machine, is it possible that VisualJVM running on different JVM is the cause?

Comment: VisualVM is always run in its own JVM (unless used from netbeans)  It only needs to be the same user and machine.

Comment: I have resolved the problem by installing "JVM monitor" plugin into Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

When you run mvn this way, these parameters are being passed into the mvn batch file. That batch file launches java, but when doing so it doesn't pass the same arguments that were received.

For the JVM to load the JMX stuff, these '-D' system properties parameters need to be passed into the java command-line, but in this case the JVM is being launched without these parameters, and then the maven java classes parse the '-D' parameters and add them as system properties. That is fine for (non-JVM-startup) system properties, but it happens too late to be effective for loading JMX.

Instead, you should try setting the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable to contain

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1100"
```

before running `mvn`.

(Note - if running on linux/unix, remember to export MAVEN_OPTS too.)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by installing "**JVM monitor**" plugin into Eclipse. However I don't consider this to be proper solution.